# ngFor using index to indentify items

Tags: angular

I have the following ngFor were images are being displayed. If an image is missing (Http 404) I simply want to hide the img element. The problem is that the imgMissing variable is global for all the elements. We could easily solve this with logic in the component file or by specifying a separate component file for the item part.

But is it possible to solve this only within the template e.g. by using the index to identify the missing image item?

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
    <img *ngIf="!imgMissing" [src]="item.imgSrc" (error)="imgMissing=true;" />
</div>
```

Comment: What defined whether or not the image is missing?

Otherwise, if you knew the missing index, `*ngIf="i != knownIndex"` or if imgSrc is blank (missing) `*ngIf="item.imgSrc"`

Comment: @silentsod thanks for your reply. I forgot to mention that I don´t know the missing index, I only get 404 error when trying to fetch the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the native onerror handler to set the style.

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
    <img [src]="item.imgSrc" onerror="this.style.display='none'" />
</div>
```